# Shift Organization algorithms (Constraint Programming + Marriage problem)

Tags: algorithms, optimization, combinatorics, constraint-programming, branch-and-bound

I want to assign people to cover shifts considering a set of constraints and preferences. Here's the problem definition:

Daily shifts must be covered by workers, who are divided in three groups:

- Trainees (Nt = 2)
- Regulars (Nr = 3)
- Experts (Ne = 7)

The organization constraints are:

- All shifts must be covered
- A Trainee must always cover a shift with an Expert
- Workers covering Friday must also cover Sunday
- Nobody can cover two shifts in a row
- Nobody works more than M shifts every D days

The process should maximize the following output:

- Workers get shifts assigned based on their preference
- Experts work as less as possible, only covering unassigned gaps
- Number of shifts are evenly distributed

My initial idea is to write a branch and bound algorithm to generate all possible combinations allowed by the constraints. I would then score each solution for each worker based on their preferences, and run a marriage algorithm to get the best combination.

The main problem is that the number of combinations is too (damn) high. Without constraints, there would be 6**30 (~1e24) possible arrangements. I know most of these will be bound, but currently I'm generating at a pace of ~1e8/minute.

I'm wondering if there are any heuristics I could apply to improve the process. Any ideas here? How does this whole thing sound?

Thanks!

---

Sample code to generate combinations:

```
def get_combinations(population, base, spots):
    if len(base) == spots:
        yield base
        return

    for candidate in population:
        combo = base + (candidate, )

        if is_viable(combo, population, spots):
            yield from get_combinations(population, combo, spots)

population = {'t1', 't2', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3'}
get_combinations(population, tuple(), 30)
```

Comment: Rather than implementing branch-and-bound yourself, I suggest you formulate this as an integer linear programming instance (or a SAT instance) and try applying an off-the-shelf ILP/SAT solver to see if they can find a solution for you.  They implement multiple techniques and heuristics that are probably beyond what anyone on person could reasonably be expected to implement on their own.

Comment: Thanks @D.W. that's exactly what I've been investigating, I'll try to solve a simpler version following this approach! For what is worth, looks like some of the real-world constraints of this problem makes finding an optimal solution impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out [this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurse_scheduling_problem) is pretty hard to solve and is still under active research. [This paper](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/123829/1/JOS_) (2004) describes the state of the art.